# Unable to get Notification form Scanner

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I am working on an application for a Zebra Technologies TC8000 scanner using the DataWedge. I'm using Android Studio 3.5 and flutter for the mobile framework.

I am using a Broadcast Receiver in my main activity and attempting to use a call back in my Dart code.

When I pull the trigger on the scanner, I see the following in logcat:

```
04-22 11:35:12.946 1009-1009/? D/ScannerPlugin: Scan status changed from SCAN_STATUS_WAITFORTRIGGER to SCAN_STATUS_SCANNING
04-22 11:35:12.946 1009-1009/? D/Client: requested to send: 110 (ScannerStateChanged): SCAN_STATUS_SCANNING
04-22 11:35:12.956 1009-1009/? D/Client: sent: 110 (ScannerStateChanged): SCAN_STATUS_SCANNING
04-22 11:35:12.956 1009-1009/? D/ScannerPlugin: Status:SCANNING;ProfileName:Profile0 (default)
04-22 11:35:12.956 1009-1009/? D/ScannerStateChanged: deserialize: state: SCAN_STATUS_SCANNING
04-22 11:35:12.966 1009-1009/? D/Protocol: parsed 110 (ScannerStateChanged): SCAN_STATUS_SCANNING
04-22 11:35:12.966 1009-1009/? D/SwipeAssistService: handleMessage(110 (ScannerStateChanged): SCAN_STATUS_SCANNING), connected clients: 1
04-22 11:35:13.416 665-665/? E/NotificationService: Not posting notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.symbol.datawedge/0x1090064 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x11 kind=[null])
04-22 11:35:13.416 665-665/? E/NotificationService: WARNING: In a future release this will crash the app: com.symbol.datawedge
04-22 11:35:13.436 1009-1009/? D/ScannerPlugin: Scan status changed from SCAN_STATUS_SCANNING to SCAN_STATUS_WAITFORTRIGGER
04-22 11:35:13.436 1009-1009/? D/Client: requested to send: 110 (ScannerStateChanged): SCAN_STATUS_WAITFORTRIGGER
04-22 11:35:13.436 1009-1009/? D/Client: sent: 110 (ScannerStateChanged): SCAN_STATUS_WAITFORTRIGGER
04-22 11:35:13.436 1009-1009/? D/ScannerPlugin: Status:WAITING;ProfileName:Profile0 (default)
04-22 11:35:13.436 1009-1009/? D/ScannerStateChanged: deserialize: state: SCAN_STATUS_WAITFORTRIGGER
04-22 11:35:13.436 1009-1009/? D/Protocol: parsed 110 (ScannerStateChanged): SCAN_STATUS_WAITFORTRIGGER
04-22 11:35:13.436 1009-1009/? D/SwipeAssistService: handleMessage(110 (ScannerStateChanged): SCAN_STATUS_WAITFORTRIGGER), connected clients: 1
```

The scan beam comes on and the scanner acknowledges the bar code read, but I'm not receiving the event. I'm concerned over the line:

```
04-22 11:35:13.416 665-665/? E/NotificationService: Not posting notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.symbol.datawedge/0x1090064 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x11 kind=[null])
```

I've checked Zebra's documents and modified my code to register the broadcast receiver. Here is my MainActivity code:

```java
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;


import com.goodyear.flutter_plugin.R;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    private static String INTENT_ACTION;
    private static String SCAN_DATA;

    private static String CHANNEL;
    private static String METHOD;
    private static String NOTIFICATION_ACTION;
    private static String NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SCANNER_STATUS;

    private Result barcodeResult;

    private void registerReceivers() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(NOTIFICATION_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void unRegisterReceivers() {
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("Barcode", "Inside onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        INTENT_ACTION = getResources().getString(R.string.activity_intent_filter_action);
        SCAN_DATA = getResources().getString(R.string.datawedge_intent_key_data);

        CHANNEL = getResources().getString(R.string.barcode_method_channel);
        METHOD = getResources().getString(R.string.barcode_method);

        NOTIFICATION_ACTION = getResources().getString(R.string.datawedge_notification_action);
        NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SCANNER_STATUS = getResources().getString(R.string.datawedge_notification_scanner_status);

        registerReceivers();

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("com.symbol.datawedge.api.APPLICATION_NAME", "com.example.intenttest");
        b.putString("com.symbol.datawedge.api.NOTIFICATION_TYPE", "SCANNER_STATUS");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
        i.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.REGISTER_FOR_NOTIFICATION", b);//(1)
        this.sendBroadcast(i);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                        Log.i("Barcode", "Inside onMethodCall");

                        if (call.method.equals(METHOD)) {
                            Log.i("Barcode", "Result = " + result);
                            barcodeResult = result;
                        }

                        Log.i("Barcode", "Leaving onMethodCall");
                    }
                }
        );

        Log.i("Barcode", "Leaving onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unRegisterReceivers();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("Barcode", "Inside onReceive");
            String action = intent.getAction();

            Log.d("Barcode", "#DataWedge-APP# Action: " + action);

            switch (action) {
                case "com.symbol.datawedge.api.NOTIFICATION_ACTION":
                    logStatus(intent);
                    break;
                case "com.com.goodyear.ACTION":
                    readScanData(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private void logStatus(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.NOTIFICATION")) {
            Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.NOTIFICATION");
            String NOTIFICATION_TYPE = b.getString("NOTIFICATION_TYPE");
            if (NOTIFICATION_TYPE != null) {
                Log.d("Barcode", "SCANNER_STATUS: status: " + b.getString("STATUS") + ", profileName: " + b.getString("PROFILE_NAME"));
            }
        }
    }

    private void readScanData(Intent intent) {
        String barCode = intent.getStringExtra(SCAN_DATA);
//            String decodedLabelType = intent.getStringExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.datawedge_intent_key_label_type));

        try {
            Log.i("Barcode", "Barcode = " + barCode);
            barcodeResult.success(barCode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //  Catch if the UI does not exist when we receive the broadcast
        }

        Log.i("Barcode", "Leaving onReceive");
    }
}
```

This is frustrating. The issue does not seem to be in my code as I have set breakpoints in the the `onReceive()` event and that method does not fire.

Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTIFICATION_ACTION is only used to notify your application that the scanner beam is scanning, IDLE etc, it does not actually contain any scan data.  I think you are confusing the DataWedge API with the DataWedge Intent Output plugin, I don't have a Flutter example but please take a look at a quick Java tutorial I did on receiving scan data from DataWedge: http://www.darryncampbell.co.uk/2017/12/13/tutorial-scan-with-datawedge-intent-output-on-zebra-devices/

I am pretty sure that error about NotificationService is unrelated to the scanner.

Your log also indicates that you are using Profile0 (default), which is the same I show in the tutorial but you may want to consider creating a dedicated Profile for your app.

Comment: I did have a look at your example and used it, in part, to model my code, along with other examples. My project, at the moment, is to simply try and get scanner output into my java code, which is proving difficult at the moment. The use of the NOTIFICATION_ACTION was simply an attempt to receive some sort of information from the scanner, which is not happening. Thank you for your input. Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are looking to get something simple working you could try running the sample app from that tutorial (https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-Intent-Example-1) and configuring DataWedge as specified in the ReadMe

Comment: thank you. I did go back and started running your basic intent example. That worked, so I transferred that code over to a flutter test project. I am now receiving barcode data in flutter.